# How i can automate Desktop apps beside the web in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I have a case in our website than when you click on Email to Friend its then the desktop outlook application open the email template and i have to check the predefined content in this email, so how i can check the email content in selenium webdriver?

The same case when i do share from the web on Telegram application.

Comment: I guess you should go with `AutoIT` http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: I am not sure if you should be testing this scenario. As it does not make any sense to me to automate any test case which involves third party application. We usually ignore this kind of application. Instead of clicking on the link, you can get text and attributes of link and verify your string. If you want to test if email is received on that email address, that is completely new scenario altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I don't automate such cases since automated tests are more about regression testing. You need to evaluate how often this functionality will change. If it is once a year, it doesn't make sense to automate it just for the sake of automating it.
You can read more about ROI of automated tests:

(a) Automated test script development time = (Hourly automation time per test * Number of automated test cases) / 8

(b) Automated test script execution time = (Automated test execution time per test * Number of automated test cases*Period of ROI) / 18

(c)Automated test analysis time = (Test Analysis time * Period of ROI) / 8

(d) Automated test maintenance time = (Maintenance time * Period of ROI) / 8

(e) Manual Execution Time = (Manual test execution time * Number of manual test cases * Period of ROI) / 8

You can find more in this article that I found on Google- https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-calculate-roi-for-test-automation

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation but I was interacting with MS-Excel in my case.
I would suggest you use AutoIT and Sikuli to automate non-browser functionality in conjunction with Selenium.

**Note:**
By importing the *autoitx4java* and *Sikuli* jar files in eclipse project you can use them along with selenium code.

Below mentioned urls should help you get started with AutoIT and Sikuli.

**AutoIT:**

http://automation-home.blogspot.in/2015/06/java-and-autoit-automating-calculator-application.html

**Sikuli:**

http://selenium-suresh.blogspot.in/2014/01/sikuli-automation-tool-integration-with.html

http://www.tothenew.com/blog/integration-of-sikuli-with-selenium-webdriver/